# Load div after page load with placeholder or animation whilst loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

first post here. 
I'm new to php so please be nice :)

I have a div that makes various api calls for a loop. (FYI Its a table of stock market companies and I need to fetch current price for each one). Naturally this slows the page down considerably. I want to to load the rest of the page first, and have a placeholder/animation while it fetches the data (this is a bonus).

FYI, I am using bootstrap if that helps.

For example:

```
                        <li class="clear">
                            <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
                                <div class="item-avatar" style="display:inline-block">
                                    <a href="<?php bp_group_permalink() ?>"><?php bp_group_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=40&height=40' ) ?></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item" style="display:inline-block">
                                    <div class="item-title"><a href="<?php bp_group_permalink() ?>"><?php bp_group_name() ?></a></div>                                  
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                            <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
                                <div class="item-meta">
                                        <div class="critix-score">
                                            <?php $groupid = bp_get_group_id(); ?>
                                            <?php echo get_totoal_avg_critix($groupid); ?>%
                                        </div>                                          
                                        <?php
                                        $group_id = bp_get_group_id();
                                        $setting = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, 'incao_info_tab_meta' );
                                        ?>                      
                                        <?php if(isset($setting['incao_trading_url']) && !empty($setting['incao_trading_url']) && !empty($setting['incao_ico_price'])){ ?>                                                                                                                                          
                                                <?php 
                                                $cmc_id = $setting['incao_trading_url'];
                                                $phi = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/'.$cmc_id.'/';                      
                                                $current_price = shell_exec('curl -s "'.$phi.'" | egrep -i price | cut -d : -f2 ');         
                                                $ico_price = $setting['incao_ico_price'];
                                                $ico_roi = $current_price / $ico_price; ?>
                                                    <?php if ($ico_roi > 1) { ?>
                                                            <div class="eth-roi alert-success" style=""><?php //echo (round($ico_roi,1)); ?>X</div> 
                                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                                            <div class="eth-roi alert-danger" style=""><?php //echo (round($ico_roi,1)); ?>X</div>                                                                                                          
                                                    <?php }
                                         } else {?>             
                                                <div class="eth-roi">--</div>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thanks guys!

---

UPDATE - I have posted the entire code. Not sure if it is the best way of doing it but it works http://cryptocritix.com if you want to see it... its the "ICOS RECENTLY TRADING" DIV

jquery, bootstrap is loaded already

Comment: In the above code, you haven't shared anything related to API calls or jQuery. Do you wanna add those so that we can help you?

Comment: Do you have any Jquery functionality that you are using. Because I assume you would want those to load first. Once those are loaded, you can then call the php script. Update the question and we can help.

Comment: @Darian jquery is already loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work, but notice my inline comments as it reveals some PHP variabels which may be not what you want. If that is the case, you will need a different approach. Let me know if this gives any results. If not, you can check the browser console if the Javascript prints any errors ;)

Also, you may want to move the CSS to your stylesheet, I wouldn't recommend to move the Javascript because now it is only loaded when `if (isset($setting['incao_trading_url']) && !empty($setting['incao_trading_url']) && !empty($setting['incao_ico_price']))` returns `true`.

```
<li class="clear">
  <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <div class="item-avatar" style="display:inline-block">
      <a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_avatar( 'type=thumb&width=40&height=40' ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="display:inline-block">
      <div class="item-title">
        <a href="<?php bp_group_permalink(); ?>"><?php bp_group_name(); ?></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:50%; float:left;">
    <div class="item-meta">
      <div class="critix-score">
        <?php $group_id = bp_get_group_id(); ?>
        <?php echo get_totoal_avg_critix($group_id); ?>%
      </div>
      <?php
        //$group_id = bp_get_group_id(); // WAS ALREADY DECLARED BUT WITHOUT '_', I ADDED THE UNDERSCORE TO THE FIRST ONE !!
        $setting = groups_get_groupmeta( $group_id, 'incao_info_tab_meta' );
      ?>
      <?php if (isset($setting['incao_trading_url']) && !empty($setting['incao_trading_url']) && !empty($setting['incao_ico_price'])) : ?>

        <?php
          $cmc_id = $setting['incao_trading_url'];
          $phi = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/'.$cmc_id.'/';
        ?>

        <style>
          /* THIS PIECE OF CSS IS RESPONSIBLE FOR THE LOADING ANIMATION .. */
          .loader {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            border-top-color: #0060a1;
            border-top-style: solid;
            border-top-width: 3px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
            animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
          }
          @-webkit-keyframes spin {
            0% {
              -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100% {
              -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
          }
          @keyframes spin {
            0% {
              transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
            100% {
              transform: rotate(360deg);
            }
          }
        </style>

        <div id="price-showing-after-page-load">
          <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>

        <?php
        /**
         * SINCE THE NEXT PIECE OF JAVASCRIPT IS EXECUTED CLIENT SIDE,
         * IT REVEALS $phi (and $cmc_id), $setting['incao_ico_price'] and API 'price' value !!
         * WOULD THAT BE AN ISSUE ?? OTHERWISE WE NEED A DIFFERENT APPROACH !!
         */
        ?>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: <?php echo $phi; ?>,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) {
                let ico_roi = data.price / <?php echo $setting['incao_ico_price']; ?>;
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                if (ico_roi > 1) {
                  $(div)
                    .addClass('eth-roi alert-success')
                    .html('<?php //echo (round($ico_roi,1)); ?>X');
                } else {
                  $(div)
                    .addClass('eth-roi alert-danger')
                    .html('<?php //echo (round($ico_roi,1)); ?>X');
                }
                $('#price-showing-after-page-load').html(div);
              }
            });
          });
        </script>

      <?php else : ?>
        <div class="eth-roi">--</div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Bob, thank you so much for attempting, it doesnt work, you can see it at http://staging3.cryptocritix.com

Comment: shows an error, something about CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: ok, tried to guess my way through it, read something about coinmarketcap only allows GET. I have changed the url to a static url, and gotten rid of the ico_roi calculation. Just want to see it working... I guess the first call would be to see if we can get any data at all via jquery using your method, but i dont know how to use jquery.

Comment: Hi, I found CORS has to do with the browser blocking requests to external websites. Jquery ajax request is GET by default, I expect there would be a workaround for this, but that would be another topic. Try searching for cors and 'access control allow origin'. I think it will work if this issue can be fixed.

Comment: hi, sorry, i found a way to get around the CORS thing by adding a trailing backslash, have no idea the logic in that but hey ho, its allowing access now, but showing an actual jquery error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ico_roi is not defined
    at Object.success ((index):3956)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at y (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4).................... will see if i can fix it but dont know java syntax

Comment: ive put the variables back in, inspecting element, it appears something is wrong with the syntax as the data.price is not fetching

Comment: Yes, a little mistake in my code indeed, the $ symbol should not be present in the javascript piece. I declared `let ico_roi` not `$ico_roi`, so change to `if (ico_roi > 1)`

Comment: still doesnt work, i removed all "$", how do i print ico_roi to check ?

Comment: console.log(ico_roi); prints to the browser console

Comment: i think the issue is getting the actual "data.price", from "url" or syntax related. How did you know to use "data.price"? from coinmarketcap documentation?

Comment: No, from your `curl` command. But you can see the full json result whit `console.log(data);`. Then you would see exactly how to get the desired data.

Comment: Hi, got it working, the json needed to be nested to get price. Also the id needed to be unique. Thanks again. I'll update the answer when I get home

Comment: Hey, good to hear ;)

Comment: Hey, could you mark the answer if it brought you to the solution? Cheers :)

Comment: if i edit it to show the changes, do you still get the points?

Comment: No idea, just give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want the api call to be executed after page load, you will need AJAX. PHP is a preprocessor script and runs ON page load.

So you could show a loading animation which will be replaced as soon as the api request data is received.

This could help you in the right direction:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.load-after-page-load-with-spinnning-animation').html(data.price);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.loading {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top-color: #0060a1;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="load-after-page-load-with-spinnning-animation" style="float:right">
  <div class="loading"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I'm not quite sure how

<div class="load-after-page-load-with-spinnning-animation" style="float:right">
  <div class="loading"></div>
</div>

relates to;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
      $('.load-after-page-load-with-spinnning-animation').html(data.price);
    }
  });
});

where would the actual api call go?

Comment: Hi, instead of using php I used jQuery to do the api call. Check https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for documentation about jQuery AJAX. I hope that helps ;)

Comment: hi im lost, would you be interested in doing it for me as a one off for payment?

Comment: I'm happy to help you out, will have a look at it again this weekend where I have time again. I don't need anything for it, shouldn't be too difficult ;)

Comment: ill paypal you something! ive spent hours reading on how to get it to work... 

you can look at the web url above.
$cmc_id is the ticker code, static and saved in my db manually.
$ico_price is a static value in my db manually. 
$current_price is the current price on coinmarketcap
$roi is return on investment

Many thanks